# Как узнать размер видео до записи на диск? MoviePy

Tags: видео, ffmpeg, moviepy

Работаю в MoviePy с видеоклипом длиной в 60 секунд, разрешением 640х640 и весом больше 8 мегабайт. Знаю все его характеристики, как .mp4 файла, так как он находится в одной из папок программы.
Задача: найти оптимальное разрешение для видео, при котором размер файла будет меньше 8 мегабайт. *(размер файла примерно 7.5мб - 8мб)*

Пробовал уменьшать видеоклип с помощью `video.resize(x)`, где x перебирал в диапазоне от 1 до 0, но чтобы узнать размер каждого из получившихся файлов, их нужно записать на диск с помощью `video.write_videofile()`, а это занимает много времени.

Вопрос:  как узнать размер видеоклипа до записи?

Через `video.video_bitrate()` вычислять размер пробовал, проблема в том, что данные о битрейте видео не обновляются после выполнения `video.resize()`, т.е. чтобы узнать актуальный битрейт, клип всё ещё необходимо записать на диск. `ffprobe`, как я понял, тоже работает лишь с видео, записанными в памяти.

Comment: Размер видеофайла зависит не от разрешения, а от битрейта, а битрейт не зависит от разрешения. Какой битрейт поставите — такой размер и получится, независимо от любых других характеристик (почти)

Comment: `Вопрос: как узнать размер видеоклипа до записи?` как уЖать - правильней будет. 1 урезать палитру(больше 24 бит не сильно то и нужно, а порой можно обойтись и 16ю), 2 ужать FPS, 3 уменьшить кол-во каналов аудио, 4 выбрать кодек получше(AV1\AVC1 до 2ух раз компактнее предыдущих, но есть не на каждой железке), 5 а потом уже и с разрешением можно будет поиграться. если повезет, может и до ~3мб сжаться.